# Using json file to give appbar logo for flutter. Facing Loading issue while navigation

Tags: flutter, loading, appbar

I wanted to show appbar logo for all the pages from a json file. Now the issue is if I use Futurebuilder
then in every page load, appbar logo awaits before showing. I tried to use shared preference but having issues. Maybe I am doing it wrong. I am a newbie in flutter. If possible please give the answer in simple way so I can understand. Or anyone can help me by creating that part for appbar. That will be helpful.

[Here is my json file for logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNos8.png)

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:models/app_logo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import './home_screen.dart';
import './login_screen.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../screens/courses_screen.dart';
import '../screens/my_courses_screen.dart';
import '../screens/my_wishlist_screen.dart';
import '../screens/account_screen.dart';
import '../widgets/filter_widget.dart';
import '../providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  List<Widget> _pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    LoginScreen(),
    LoginScreen(),
    LoginScreen(),
  ];
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
  bool _isSearching = false;
  final searchController = TextEditingController();

  Future<AppLogo> futureLogo;

  Future<AppLogo> fetchMyLogo() async {
    var url = BASE_URL + '/app_logo';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
        // then parse the JSON.
        print(response.body);
        return AppLogo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      }
      // print(extractedData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.fetchMyLogo();
    // Provider.of<Auth>(context).tryAutoLogin().then((_) {});
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      final _isAuth = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).isAuth;

      if (_isAuth) {
        _pages = [
          HomeScreen(),
          MyCoursesScreen(),
          MyWishlistScreen(),
          AccountScreen(),
        ];
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String value) {
    final searchText = searchController.text;
    if (searchText.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    searchController.clear();
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      CoursesScreen.routeName,
      arguments: {
        'category_id': null,
        'seacrh_query': searchText,
        'type': CoursesPageData.Search,
      },
    );
    // print(searchText);
  }

  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedPageIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: kSecondaryColor, //change your color here
        ),
        title: !_isSearching
            ? FutureBuilder<AppLogo>(
          future: fetchMyLogo(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(),
              );
            } else {
              if (snapshot.error != null) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Error Occured"),
                );
              } else {
                return Image.network(
                  snapshot.data.darkLogo,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  height: 27,
                );
              }
            }
          },
        )
        : TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Search Here',
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          controller: searchController,
          onFieldSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
        ),
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: kSecondaryColor,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _isSearching = !_isSearching;
                  });
                }),
          ],
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _showFilterModal(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
        backgroundColor: kDarkButtonBg,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('Course'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
            title: Text('My Course'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
            title: Text('Wishlist'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            title: Text('Account'),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
        unselectedItemColor: kSecondaryColor,
        selectedItemColor: kSelectItemColor,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I will use something like `bool gotLogo = false`, and set `gotLogo = true` after getting the actual logo from the server. While inside Widget build part, will use something like `title: !_isSearching && !gotLogo ? Text('Loading') : !_isSearching && gotLogo ? FutureBuilder<AppLogo>(.....) : TextFormField(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can do to reduce the load time of the logo in your AppBar. Since this AppBar is common between the tabs, you should only load it once and avoid loading again every time the tab is changed.

First is to use `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder` to reduce the number of loads.

```dart
// Create a StreamController
final _controller = StreamController<AppLogo>();

// Run fetchMyLogo() in your initState() like in your code

// In your fetchMyLogo(), add the result to the stream
fetchMyLogo() async {

    // ... other lines

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      var logo = AppLogo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      _controller.add(logo);
    }

// Then, listen to this logo in your StreamBuilder
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        // ... other lines

        title: !_isSearching
            ? StreamBuilder<AppLogo>(
          stream: _controller.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {

          // ... other lines
```

Second is to use the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) instead of `Image.network`, so that your logo image is cached, which reduce load time for network images.

```dart
return CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: snapshot.data.darkLogo,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 27,
       );
```

**Small note**: For each of the page in your `_pages` list, if you want the page to persist (not reload after every tab change), you can use the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to persist the state of each page, or use `IndexedStack` like:

```dart
// The IndexedStack will load all pages initially
body: IndexedStack(
        children: _pages,
        index: _selectedPageIndex,
      ),
// ... other lines
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked just as I wanted. But there is one issue. When it load for the first time, app logo's position start in center off the appbar and after that just within seceond it auto changed to left side. I wanted it to show it in left side. I used the alignment in CachedNetworkImage to "Alignment.centerLeft" But it still not worked. I just change as you suggested in the code. @Bach